# How to parse DataFrame with specific column and write it to different excel sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I want to parse specific column in my dataframe and write to sheets in one excel file? I tried below code:

```
for groups in z3.cats:
    group=z3[z3['cats']==groups]
    group.to_csv('group.csv',encoding='gbk')
```

Here is the example data:

```
cats    predict 
[0.9, 1.0)  99% 
[0.1, 0.2)  30% 
[0.1, 0.2)  51% 
[0.0, 0.1)  0% 
[0.3, 0.4)  12% 
.
. 
[0.9, 1.0)  100%
```

I want to group `[0.9,1.0)` in `cats2` column,and put them in one excel sheet name `[0.9,1.0)` , and `[0.1, 0.2)` in another excel sheet name `[0.1, 0.2)` .and make the two sheet is in one excel file.

Comment: Can you share a complete example?

Comment: cats2 predict3
[0.9, 1.0) 99%
[0.1, 0.2) 30%
[0.1, 0.2) 51%
[0.0, 0.1) 0%
[0.3, 0.4) 12%
[0.0, 0.1) 0%
[0.9, 1.0) 83%
[0.8, 0.9) 76%
[0.0, 0.1) 3%
[0.4, 0.5) 53%
[0.1, 0.2) 30%
[0.9, 1.0) 99%
[0.9, 1.0) 100%
[0.0, 0.1) 9%
[0.9, 1.0) 99%
[0.9, 1.0) 98%
[0.1, 0.2) 2%
[0.9, 1.0) 86%
[0.6, 0.7) 86%
[0.2, 0.3) 54%
[0.0, 0.1) 10%
[0.0, 0.1) 1%
[0.0, 0.1) 1%
[0.8, 0.9) 75%
[0.4, 0.5) 89%
[0.4, 0.5) 86%
[0.1, 0.2) 16%
[0.9, 1.0) 88%
[0.4, 0.5) 56%
[0.5, 0.6) 62%
[0.9, 1.0) 100%

Comment: for example i want to group [0.9,1.0) in cats2 column,and put them in one excel sheet name [0.9,1.0) , and [0.1, 0.2) in another excel sheet name[0.1, 0.2)  .and make the two sheet is in one excel file.

Comment: Put your example and additional detail into your original question

Comment: Already add them to my question,thanks~

Comment: There is still a lot of information missing that is preventing anyone from helping you. You've put in a for loop but what about the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had been perfectly solved
here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd   
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('group.xlsx')
for groups in infos['cats']:      
    group=infos[infos['cats']==groups]
    group.to_excel(writer,encoding='gbk',sheet_name="{0}".format(groups))
writer.save()
```